# Scala: Type resolution of an inner case class in extending classes

Tags: scala, traits, case-class

I have something similar to a tree like structure.
I have a trait T. And two classes (A and B) that extends T.

A is like the root node that creates new instances from B while B itself can create new instances from B.

In trait T I define a case class C that I use to save some specific values as well as a List[C] (lets call it listC to keep things simple) that contains all instances of C.

Also every B knows its parent. What I want to do is listC = parent.listC. However this does not work as listC expects the typ List[C] but gets List[parent.C].

How can I solve this issue?

Additionally here are some solutions that I tried but didn't work / are not possible:

- I can not define the case class outside of the trait as its values have types that only get defined within the trait.
- An easy solution would be to drop the class and use a Tuple instead. However I would like to stick with the class to enhance readability. It's just nice to call x.varName as x._4

Comment: Is parent.C a different type than C?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the type `C` in different subclasses of `T` to be the same type you cannot define the type as a path dependent type in `T`.

`Tuple2[A.D, A.E]` will not be the same as `Tuple2[B.D, B.E]`, this is the exact same problem.

But if a tuple would work, then you should be able to just define the `C` case class in the companion object of `T` for example just as well as using a tuple.

One way to do this could be to put bounds on what the nested types can be and use a common supertype in your `C`/`Tuples`